# A Question on Bayesian updating with uninformative prior

Tags: conditional-probability, bayesian

Say a variable $x$ follows uninformative prior on $\left(-\infty,\infty\right)$ and if $x<x^{*}$, there is a signal generated with probability $p$; with probability $1-p$, no signal is ever generated. If $x\geq x^{*}$, no signal is generated as well.

I understand that conditional on observing the signal, the posterior becomes uninformative on $\left(-\infty,x^{*}\right)$. However, what is the posterior conditional on not observing the signal? In particular, is this still uninformative distribution on $\left(-\infty,\infty\right)$?

Comment: No, not observing the signal gives you information about $x$. Imagine if $p$ is very close to one.

Comment: Sure, but is there an easy way to characterize the posterior upon not observing the signal, for general $p$?

Comment: Bayes rule like always.

Comment: This “uninformative prior on $(-\infty,\infty)$” thing is not very well defined and taints the whole operation. But if we just treat $x<x^*$ as a binary event, then we can show that if the signal is not observed the posterior probability of it is $(1-p ) /(2-p).$ (Assuming a prior of $1/2$ of course.)

Comment: In other words if you had a “flat improper prior” you should change it to an improper posterior that is a step function where the side above $x^*$ is higher than the side below by a factor of $1/(1-p).$